# SQL Dynamic Query generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have 2 tables like below[image]

here i need to get all the rows from second table based on each row from the first table which matches **Field1value and field2value combination**.Second table select column will decide by first table field1 and field2 respectively,and I need to remove the duplicate row if any,for example last row in second table satisfies the condition of 1 and 3 row of first table.

How to format this query?.

Comment: Please read the instruction on the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select 'select distinct percentage from table2 where '+Field1+' ='+ ''''+Field1value+ ''''+' and '+Field2+' = '+  ''''+Field2value+ '''' from table11
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, If I want to fetch for all rows from table 2 based on all available combination from table 1, how can i do that ,

Comment: you need to do some manual work in this, to achieve this you can add union in the beginning and the execute this code once you get successful message, copy the complete result set and in the query editor remove the first union keyword and execute it. this should work